# How to change foreground of WPF DataGridCell depending on background?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I want to change the color of the foreground of a DataGridCell in a DataGrid when the background is anything but white.  So I wrote this xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="White" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                     Value="Transparent">
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="Black" />
         </DataTrigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Using a converter to test the input and binding, I can see the correct values being generated by the binding.  However, the setter does not appear to fire.

edit1: I am setting the cell background color via a converter

edit2: Actually, the background of the textblock of the datagridcell is being set via a converter

Comment: How are you setting Cell background color?

Comment: Updated question with answer

Comment: Are your `Transparent`s the same? ie `rgba(0,0,0,0)` and `rgba(255,255,255,0)` are both transparent

Comment: This link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e9d47ae4-34c3-40ed-82d9-afdce419098b/change-textblock-foreground-color-based-on-its-background-color?forum=wpf suggests `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self},Path=Background.Color}`

Comment: I just switched the trigger to a converter instead of a datatrigger so I could get more visibility via the debugger.  Now I understand what is wrong, thanks to Ganesh's question.

Answer (score 0):

I set the background of the TextBlock inside the DataGridCell via a converter.  So the background of the DataGridCell isn't actually being changed, which is what I bound to.